# Better way of handling seasonality in linear regression

Tags: regression, python, seasonality

I have inherited a simple single OLS linear regression model (Python statsmodels) of which attempts to handle some prior view on seasonality in the relationship by modelling data as two seasons by splitting and training model separately.

What would be a better way of modelling this relationship?

I could include the month in the dataset as a dummy variable and perform multiple linear regression, but I wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: Please use capital letters appropriately.

Comment: thanks for the grammatical correction. i wonder if you have any insight into the question posed?

Comment: You just keep typing without caps... Regarding the question, there are insufficient details to give you specific advice. It would be more helpful to know what process you are modelling and what is characteristic to it.

Comment: Sorry, I admit I was baiting you above.